# Force devise user to log out from background task

Tags: devise

Is there a way to force devise user to be logged out from within a model? (or anywhere outside controllers)

Comment: I can scarcely believe how difficult this is turning out to be... I figured it would take 30 seconds but I'm 30 minutes in with no answer...

Comment: FWIW I gave up and settled for a stupid hack, a before_filter calling the sign_out method from devise if a condition is met on that user ... in my case I just used sign_out current_user if current_user.last_sign_in_at < Time.at(xxxx) but you could set a flag in the db in a background task and do something similar